# Spring Security returns 403 instead of 401 and creates invalid Redis session cookie

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-redis

I'm using Spring Security and Spring Data Redis to keep track of user sessions with custom roles and entitlements. When I try to hit a PreAuthorized endpoint without a session cookie in my browser, it should return a 401. Instead a new (invalid) session cookie is created and the endpoint returns a 403.

Here's my SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf().disable().cors();
    }
}
```

I'm also using `MethodSecurityConfig` and an implementation of `UserDetails` to parse the custom fields from the user authentication.

Comment: add  AuthenticationFailureHandler and edit the response status to 401
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler

Comment: @RoieBeck Thank you but that didn't work. When running the backend in debug mode, I put a breakpoint inside the failure handler and it's not reaching it.

Comment: just making sure you added this line after the autenticated:

```.failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());```

Comment: @RoieBeck yessir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix, for anyone who encounters a similar issue down the line:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()   //let redis handle session creation
                .csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .requestCache().disable().exceptionHandling().and()                         //prevent exception creating duplicate session
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()                     //all endpoints need auth
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                        new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));                 //return 401 on no session
    }
```